# Wpf button size with trigger

Tags: wpf

I want to change Button size when I press button.
But, under source code isn't working

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="350"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="90"/>
</Trigger>
```

What can I do for making bigger button?

Comment: Please post all relevant parts of your XAML.

Comment: I can't upload button's full code. Maybe I think my code is so long....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
<Button Content="Press">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="350"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="90"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Make sure that you don't explicitly set the `Width` and `Height` properties of the `Button` element itself:

```
<Button Width="..." Height="..."
```

A local values takes precedence over a value set by a `Style`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence